# Laravel cast model values when using Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

When returning a model using resource  `created_at`  and  `updated_at` `casting` is working fine,
but when i modify the `toArray()` function the casting is not working !

in my model :

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d:h',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d:h',
];
```

in resource :

```
 public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'value' => $this->value,
        'box' =>  new BoxResource($this->box),
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
}
```

in controller :

```
  public function index(Request $request)
{

    return CurrencyResource::collection(
        Currency::where("user_id", "=", $request->user()->id)
          
            ->paginate($per_page)
    );
}
```

How to make the casting work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By it not working, you mean the timestamps revert to carbon instances? You could just use the format method then.

```
'created_at' => $this->created_at->format('Y-m-d:h'),
'updated_at' => $this->updated_at->format('Y-m-d:h'),
```

Comment: good answer but is there is any way to fix this globaly

Comment: The documentation is clear on the subject of date casting using the `$cast`. "This format will be used when the model is serialized to an array or JSON:"